# rsync and cp to nfs hangs after execution

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

I have a NAS on my LAN that I can access without any issue. It's mounted on my machine as follows:
`mount -t nfs 192.168.2.9:/nfs/Public /mnt/nfs/nas/Public/`.

When I execute the following command `rsync --progress video.mkv /mnt/nfs/nas/Public`, rsync reaches 100% in a few seconds then hangs for a few minutes. The same happens with `cp` or `mv`. It doesn't display any error or anything, it simply hangs doing seemingly nothing.

How can I solve this so that the process doesn't hang for so long once it's done with its work?

EDIT:
Some extra information. I've tried executing it with strace and this is what I get at the end of the process:

```
write(4, "\4\200\0\7\0\324\205\362\377Q`\277\343gzn\351\7\326\312\3368\1\242\362\203Y\336(\264\f\n"..., 32776) = 32776
    576,142,724 100%  227.98MB/s    0:00:02 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
) = 65
munmap(0x7f70c300f000, 266240)          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
select(6, [5], [4], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (out [4], left {tv_sec=59, tv_usec=999999})
write(4, "\235\275\0\7\215\177\244;\345!\375 \212!\243+\357q\32?\31D\34\3749\251\376\355\254Y\254\304"..., 48545) = 48545
select(6, [5], [], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [5], [], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [5], [], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(6, [5], [], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [5], left {tv_sec=30, tv_usec=672979})
read(5, "\3\0\0\7\0\0\0", 32768)        = 7
select(6, [5], [4], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (out [4], left {tv_sec=59, tv_usec=999997})
write(4, "\2\0\0\7\0\0", 6)             = 6
select(6, [5], [4], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (out [4], left {tv_sec=59, tv_usec=999997})
write(4, "\1\0\0\7\0", 5)               = 5
select(6, [5], [], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [5], left {tv_sec=59, tv_usec=999998})
read(5, "\1\0\0\7\0", 32768)            = 5
wait4(5734, 0x7fff0c840524, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=20000000}, NULL) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5734, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 5734
wait4(-1, 0x7fff0c83fe14, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
wait4(5734, 0x7fff0c840524, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f70c3105030}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f70c3105030}, NULL, 8) = 0
wait4(5734, 0x7fff0c840504, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

When it starts hanging, it is stuck at the first `select(6, [5], [], [5], {tv_sec=60, tv_usec=0}) = 0` (initially without the Timeout between brackets)

Comment: may depend on how big the video is and how fast your NFS is. What happens with small files?

Comment: The file is only 500Mb. And rsync reaches 100% in a few seconds. It seems to hang **after** the transfer is over

Comment: Well, "only" 500 Mb may be a lot if your NFS is slow. What's the response to a `ping -nq -c100  192.168.2.9`?

Comment: 100 packets transmitted, 100 received, 0% packet loss, time 99159ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.998/13.114/149.963/21.890 ms

Comment: How many packets your video could require? 500M * 8 / 1450 = 27856 packets (of 1450 bits each). 27.5 k packages at 13ms each will give around 5 minutes. Is it taking much more than that?

Comment: No, that's about the time it takes. But this would mean that something is wrong with my network because 100Mb per minute seems excessively slow

Comment: Well, maths talk here, there's a problem with your NFS network connection. Troubleshooting NFS client: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS/Troubleshooting#Intermittent_client_freezes_when_copying_large_files

Comment: I tried using sync and it didn't help. But if the ping is already slow, doesn't that mean that the network (or my NAS) is slow and this is not related to NFS?

Comment: Probably, this is my result over the same subnet `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.838/0.995/1.535/0.159 ms`. Try pinging another host on that subnet to compare.